# Fonts always thicker in Firefox than Chrome regardless of font-family

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-face

I am implementing `@font-face` into a small experimental site of mine:

http://mutanttractor.github.com/StackOverflow-Android-Dashboard/

In Chrome the header text looks like this:

[image: Chrome]

In Firefox 3.6 and 4b12 it looks like this:

[image: Firefox]

The 2 font is of the exact same weight and size, but this occurs no matter what the face is, even if I don't use `@font-face` - standard system fonts display the same irregularity, has anyone else experienced this?

Not only that, the text boxes are bigger too...

I'm on OSX 10.6 ;)

Comment: They are the same weight on both browsers on Windows.

Comment: Comparing Safari, Chrome, and Firefox on Windows, Safari seems more like Firefox in the rendering of your title, but it's not identical. Chrome seems to be doing its own anti-aliasing, and doing it really nicely; with both Safari and Firefox the title looks worse.

Comment: welcome to cross-browser differences, plain and simple. that's a minor example too - start doing stuff with line-height and padding, then check it out in IE and Firefox.

Comment: @BoltClock well maybe it's a configuration thing but they definitely don't look the same to me.

Comment: @jpea I am more than familiar with x-browser stuff, but it doesn't make sense how a browser can mutate the font-weight - that is one thing a browser SHOULDN'T do...

Comment: @Pointy I agree chrome's looks gorgeous, It doesnt make sense to me how a browser can mutate font-weight... margins etc makes sense but not the appearance of a font?

Comment: Well the "weight" is not really that different - I think it's more of a visual effect. It probably also varies by the sort of display you've got and maybe the system font smoothing setting. My Firefox results don't look as fat as yours.

Comment: When I looked into Typekit, I came across some other answers that relate - on the Mac, each browser has it's own font rendering engine. On Windows, every browser except IE shares the same system-wide engine. IE has it's own that others can't tie into. It ends up that when you use Typekit, most fonts on Windows look like crap, except for IE. On the Mac, all look great, but they vary. Probably a very similar (if not exact) situation that you're running across) since Typekit uses @font-face when it can.

Comment: you have read this http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/03/02/the-font-face-rule-revisited-and-useful-tricks/

Comment: @jpea on Windows, the results are significantly different between *all* browsers - they *all* appear to use their own code, or at least they all parameterize the system libraries differently.

Comment: check this article out - http://blog.typekit.com/2010/10/05/type-rendering-on-the-web/

Comment: and this - http://blog.typekit.com/2010/10/15/type-rendering-operating-systems/

Comment: I tried out your link above and i can't tell the difference between chrome and Firefox. Both look the same

Comment: Have realised it may be that Chrome renders text-shadow INSIDE the text and Firefox renders it OUTSIDE the text?

Comment: 8 years later and this is still true... I was just searching how to fix that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me, in Chrome 9 on Windows 7 (vs. FF 3.6), if I disable the "text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;", the font thickens and matches how FF looks.

Comment: ah ha! he didn't mention that he was doing text effects :-)

Comment: Yep, Chrome renders `text-shadow` INSIDE the font where as Firefox renders it OUTSIDE the font... I'll file a bug with Chrome/mozilla, what do we prefer?

Comment: @MylesGray I like Chrome's rendering better. Firefox doesn't know about `text-shadow`, so it just drops it. (don't try `-moz-text-shadow`, it won't work either) See http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/css/cross-browser-drop-shadows.

Comment: @Nyuszika7H funny, I rather Chrome's rendering.

Comment: @Nyuszika7H Firefox 4 DOES support `text-shadow`: http://maettig.com/code/css/text-shadow.html